# Making slack modal hitting Request URL only during submit

Tags: slack, slack-api, slack-block-kit, slack-dialog

I'm currently making a modal in slack via slack app (modal example below)

---

[image]

---

Based by their docs and instruction, each time any of the sections are changed it will send api request to my defined URL.

Are there any options that can disable that so that i will only do an api call when submit action is being called, since making api call each time a section is being changed can be pretty spammy.

Have been looking into it but couldn't find any answer for that.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Best you can do is configure your handler to ignore those requests.

For example, if you have a button with a value of "submit", you can check for that and ignore all others.

```
if (payload.actions[0].value != 'submit') { return; }
```

Comment: This literally saved my brain. I'd been stuck on this for a whole day.